# How to stop code execution before the Subform loads?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Navigation Control with several tabs. I want one of these tabs to behave more like a command button. When clicked, I want it to open a webpage.

```
Public Sub navOpenSO_Click()
    Shell "explorer ""https://stackoverflow.com/"""
End Sub
```

Works as expected. The webpage loads and then the form loads, but since there's no Navigation Target Name it just loads a blank screen. I'd like the navigation to stay on whatever page the user was on before they clicked navOpenSO.

I tried this

```
Private Sub navOpenSO_Enter()
    Shell "explorer ""https://stackoverflow.com/"""
    End
End Sub
```

And this

```
Private Sub navOpenSO_GotFocus()
    Shell "explorer ""https://stackoverflow.com/"""
    End
End Sub
```

But this does NOT stop code execution. How can I prevent the blank screen from loading? Thank you, SO.

Comment: What is the `Subform`?

Comment: There is no subform. Clicking navOpenSO just loads a blank screen. I've edited the post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a routine to save the current tab target in a tempvar (or public variable) :

```
Sub Save_Current_Tab()
    TempVars.Add "CurrentTab", Navigation_Control.SelectedTab.NavigationTargetName
End Sub
```

2- Call this routine in form_load and also every navigation_button_click (except the one that has no target) :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Save_Current_Tab
End Sub

Private Sub NavigationButton_1_Click()
    Save_Current_Tab
End Sub
...
...
Private Sub NavigationButton_nnn_Click()
    Save_Current_Tab
End Sub
```

3- Edit the navOpenSO_Click as follows :

```
Private Sub navOpenSO_Click()
    Dim a
    a = Split(TempVars("CurrentTab"), ".")
    If LCase(a(0) = "form") Then
        DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, a(1), "[your form name].NavigationSubform"
    Else
        DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToReport, a(1), "[your form name].NavigationSubform"
    End If
    
    Shell "explorer ..."
End Sub
```

P.S. : This code is tested and works. But also consider using a simple button placed over navigation control.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar and posted it as an answer. No TempVars or additional subroutines required, but yeah I might just end up doing the command button approach.  That comes with its own set of issues because navOpenSO is on a _sub row_ of a navigation control. I'd have to show the button only when its parent tab is selected in the main row and hide it when any other main tab is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own temp solution here:

```
Private Sub navOpenSO_Enter()
    Shell "explorer ""https://stackoverflow.com/"""
    On Error Resume Next
    navOpenSO.NavigationTargetName = Me!NavigationSubform.Form.Name

    'below code is only required if some target objects are reports:
    if err then _
         navOpenSO.NavigationTargetName = Me!NavigationSubform.Report.Name
End Sub
```

Better than nothing, but this approach **reloads** the current form. I'm still hoping there's a solution out there that leaves the form as is.